# How to Show an Local image till the NetworkImage() Loads Up in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, load, networkimageview

```
            new CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(url),
                              radius: 45.0,
                            )
```

I Want to show a local image in `CircleAvatar` until the `NetworkImage` fully loads from the internet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may want to try a [`FadeInImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) wrapped in a [`ClipOval`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html). `FadeInImage` provides a `placeholder` property you can use while the network image is loading.

Note: `ClipOval` can be expensive if you do it a lot, so use it sparingly.

Comment: how can I use placeholder for "NetworkImage" until "NetworkImage" is loaded? any example will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

**There is a new official widget for this now!**

First, create a folder called `assets` in the project root directory.

Then, mention the folder in `pubspec.yaml` file (also found in the project root directory):

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

You can put a picture there, for example, put this as `./assets/loading.gif`.

[image: Loading.gif]

(If you changed files in assets folder, hot reload won't work. Make sure you restart the app entirely.)

Now you can refer to the loading file in the code:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
  placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
  image: 'https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg?raw=true',
);
```

For more details: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images#from-asset-bundle

Comment: FadeInImage cannot be passed as the image to the CircleAvatar

Comment: My widget needs 'imageProvider'. Kindly suggest how can I use your FadeInImage and network image solutions to show image? Thanks.

Comment: I am using photo_view package available at https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view. My code is as: PhotoView(
                  imageProvider: NetworkImage(
                    widget.photoPath.toString(),
                  ),),  Kindly suggest how can I use placeholder image until network image is loaded. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

Use a `StateflWidget` and you can add a `listener` to the `ImageStream` and override the `initState` to trigger a replacement between the local image and the one obtained from the internet when it is fully loaded.

I have used a high resolution image to show the loading time:

[image]

```
  var _loadImage = new AssetImage(
      'assets/img/basic2-090_loader_loading-512.png');
  var _myEarth = new NetworkImage(
      "http://qige87.com/data/out/73/wp-image-144183272.png");
  bool _checkLoaded = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myEarth.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener((_, __) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _checkLoaded = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(child: new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle,),
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Theme
                .of(context)
                .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            backgroundImage: _checkLoaded ? _loadImage : _myEarth,
          ),)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: BoxDecoration do not have width and height property

Comment: this is on the Container widget not BoxDecoration

Comment: This solved my problem, the key thing I needed to know when the image was loaded.

Comment: how can I show "CircularProgressIndicator" instead of backgroundImage _loadImage. Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `frameBuilder` property. The good thing: you can implement your custom placeholder widget here.

```dart
Image.network('https://example.com/my-image',
  height: 100,
  frameBuilder: (context, child, frame, _) {
    if (frame == null) {
      // fallback to placeholder
      return MyPlaceholderWidget();
    }
    return child;
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two way to solve your problem

**1)  Using Image.network :** If you want to show progressbar,simmer or any other widget when image loading.

```
  Image.network(
      "URL",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) {
          return child;
        }else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
            ),
          );
        }
      },       
  )
```

**2) Using FadeInImage :** If you want to display your local image when network image loading

```
 FadeInImage.assetNetwork( 
    image:"URL",
    placeholder:"assets/loading.png" // your assets image path
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
```

Comment: My widget needs 'imageProvider'. Kindly suggest how can I use your solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I am using photo_view package available at https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view. My code is as: PhotoView(
                  imageProvider: NetworkImage(
                    widget.photoPath.toString(),
                  ),),  Kindly suggest how can I use placeholder image until network image is loaded. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

While large images load, show a fallback asset!

```
 new PlutoImage.networkWithPlaceholder("http://68.media.tumblr.com/f7e2e01128ca8eb2b9436aa3eb2a0a33/tumblr_ogwlnpSpcU1sikc68o1_1280.png", new Image.asset("assets/placeholder.png"));
```

https://github.com/FaisalAbid/pluto

Answer (score 3):

You can Use **FadeInImage**.

*Use a placeholder from asset*

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              placeholder: "assets/images/image1.png",
                              image:"URL"
                                ),
```

*Use a placeholder from memory*

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                      placeholder: localImageBytes,
                                      image:"URL"
                                    ),
```

Comment: I am using photo_view package available at https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view. My code is as: PhotoView(
                  imageProvider: NetworkImage(
                    widget.photoPath.toString(),
                  ),),  Kindly suggest how can I use placeholder image until network image is loaded. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh Please create a new question

Comment: Thanks Abir, I have solved the issue, another stackoverflow user shared the best solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a package named [flutter_url_image_load_fail](https://github.com/DigaoParceiro/flutter_url_image_load_fail) to define the *loading* and *failed to load* widgets:

```
LoadImageFromUrl(
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png', //Image URL to load
    (image) => image, //What widget returns when the image is loaded successfully
    () => Text('Loading...'), //What widget returns when the image is loading
    (IRetryLoadImage retryLoadImage, code , message){ //What widget returns when the image failed to load
        return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Try Again'),
            onPressed: (){
                retryLoadImage.retryLoadImage(); //Call this method to retry load the image when it failed to load
            },
        );
    },
    requestTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5) //Optionally set the timeout
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `foregroundImage` with `NetworkImage as profile image, and use` backgroundImage`with`AssetImage` as placeholder image, like this:

```dart
const CircleAvatar(
  radius: 60,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/avatar.png'), // Placeholder
  foregroundImage: NetworkImage('https://xxx.xxx.xx.jpg'), // Profile
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new `cached_network_image` package that has a "loading" and an "error" images. Along with auto image caching. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493334/5502121

You can set as a placeholder anything you want, for example from your assets use  `Image.asset('assets/images/my_placeholder.png')`