# Flutter - Default image to Image.network when it fails

Tags: android, asynchronous, networking, dart, flutter

Is there any way you can control exceptions launched by Image.network() so you can provide it a default AssetImage ?

Comment: What do you mean by exception ? ]

Comment: Error, for example trying to read a url that doesn't exist

Comment: You can return an `Image.asset` from the `errorBuilder` property when using `Image.network`. All the answers below refer to solutions that don't use `Image.network`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It depends on your use case, but one way to do it is to use [`FadeInImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) which has a property of `img` for the image that is intended to load, and `placeholder`, well, for the placeholder

```
FadeInImage(image: NetworkImage(url), placeholder: AssetImage(assetName)
```

You can also listen until the image is loaded and show a placeholder yourself until fetching the image resolves.

**pseudo code**

```
bool _loaded = false;
var img = Image.network(src);
var placeholder = AssetImage(assetName)

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  img.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener((i, b) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() => _loaded = true);
    }
  });     
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  return YourWidget(
    child: _loaded ? img : placeholder,
  );
}
```

Comment: `You can also listen until the image is loaded` talking about `ImageProvider` would help here. As image contains no listenable.

Answer (score 32):

You can do with FadeInImage.assetNetwork

```
 child: new Container(
      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: 'assets/place_holder.jpg',
          image:url
      )
  )
```

and in pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
  - assets/place_holder.jpg
```

Comment: how to handle null url with FadeInImAGE??

Comment: you should put full path, not just name.

Comment: placeholder requires absolute path. relative path is not working! Any reasons or suggestions ?

Comment: @Md.Sulayman use this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737494/5219642

Answer (score 30):

There is a new package called `cached_network_image` which does what you need.
Here you can set a "loading" image and an "error" image right out of the box.

> A flutter library to show images from the internet and keep them in the cache directory.
>   https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image#-readme-tab-

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

or you can use your own asset image as a placeholder for example:

```
...
placeholder: (context, url) => {return Image.asset('assets/img/my_placeholder.png');},
```

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.1
```

and import in your dart code:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
```

Comment: this: placeholder: (context, url) => {return Image.asset('assets/img/my_placeholder.png');}, does not work at all

Comment: @Kornel try using  (context) => Image.asset('assets/img/my_placeholder.png'),

Answer (score 23):

You can use the loadingBuilder, and erroBuilder properties as specified in the widget  official documentation:

```
               Image.network(
                  'https://example.com/image.jpg',
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                    print(error); //do something
                  },
                  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                      ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                            : null,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/loadingBuilder.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageErrorWidgetBuilder.html

Answer (score 4):

### 100% Solution,

1. add the asset image in pubspec.yaml file, which you want to set as default image.
2. copy the whole code and use this code where you want to implement.

   ```
   FadeInImage(
       image:NetworkImage("your_image_url"),
       placeholder: const AssetImage("your_default_image_path"),
       imageErrorBuilder:(context, error, stackTrace) {
          return Image.asset('your_default_image_path',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
          );
       },
       fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

Image.Network is not providing any feature/functionality to show error widget if Image not loaded successfully due to any reason.This means your URL should be correct always?

Flutter team uploaded new video about Image Widget on 13-01-2020 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oIAs-0G4mw) but still they didn't provide any solution.We hope the flutter team will resolve this issue soon.

Solution: 
You can use Cached network image which is providing a lot of features/functionalities to load image from URL. 
To read more about Cached network image please visit:

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Sample code of Package:

```
CachedNetworkImage(   
imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",  
imageBuilder: 
(context, imageProvider) => 
    Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
     ),   
    ),   
 placeholder: (context, url) => 
   CircularProgressIndicator(),  
 errorWidget: (context, url, error) 
  => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found the way You can use this

```
     SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: FadeInImage(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
            fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  fadeInCurve: Curves.easeInExpo,
                  fadeOutCurve: Curves.easeOutExpo,
                  placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/common_screen/ic_default_image.jpg"),
                  image: NetworkImage(imageURL
                  ),
                  imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/common_screen/ic_default_image.jpg"));
                  },
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         imageUrl: map['message'],
         placeholder: (context, url) =>
         Shimmer.fromColors(
         baseColor: HexColor("#fcfcfc"),
         highlightColor: HexColor("#edebe6"),
         child: Image.network(
         fit: BoxFit.cover,"https://www.haliburtonforest.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/placeholder-square.jpg")),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
   const Icon(Icons.error), )
```

you can use this code to show a beautiful image loading animation,

**add these dependencies to your pubspec.yaml.**

shimmer: ^2.0.0

hexcolor: ^2.0.7

cached_network_image: ^3.2.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loadingBuilder property`

```
Image.network(
    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/falcon.jpg',
    loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
        ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
      if (loadingProgress == null) {
        return child;
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
              ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                  loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
              : null,
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

this code will show image loading progress as a `CircularProgressIndicator`.