# How can I have an ImageProvider<Object> from a CircularProgressIndicator to be use with FadeInImage in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to display a CircularProgressIndicator while an image is loading using a FadeInImage in Flutter. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522800/make-fadeinimage-memorynetwork-render-circular-cropped-image)